# click event only if the object is directly clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the example below how to write console only if `.bradio` is clicked, and not `button`
i.e. on button click `bradio.eq(1)` should be checked, but without console writing

```js
$('.bradio').on('change', function(){
    console.log('onchange');
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.bradio').eq(1).click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' class='bradio' name='bradio'  value='pub' title='PUBLIC'>
<input type='radio' class='bradio' name='bradio'  value='priv' title='PRIVATE'>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select an element without manually creating a click event, set its `checked` property:

```js
$('.bradio').on('change', function() {
  console.log('onchange');
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('.bradio').eq(1).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="bradio" name="bradio" value="pub" title="PUBLIC">
<input type="radio" class="bradio" name="bradio" value="priv" title="PRIVATE">
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```